# Node.js express: store req.ip to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, ip

I have the following code in which I am able to print the external ip and port of the connecting client to my http server. Is it possible to store the ip and port to a variable? Globally declaring a variable and altering it inside `app.use(...)` does not seem to work.

```
var port = 3000;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.ip);
    console.log(req.hostname);
    console.log(req.connection.remotePort);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log(`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:${port}`);
});

var openURL = require('opn');
console.log("Opening Server URL")
openURL(`http://127.0.0.1:${port}`);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it. Where are you wanting access to the value of ip?

Comment: And it depends on how you define a global variable - file level declarations within  the main or node.js  script files are variables within a closure so you can't access them by name from another script that has been "required".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reputation is too low, so I can't comment unfortunately, but I don't see where in your code you try to store the clients IP, and port globally?

I don't see why that wouldn't work.
I just tested it locally, and this works just fine:

```
var port = 3000
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var clientIP = null
var clientPORT = null

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    clientIP = req.ip
    clientPORT = req.connection.remotePort
    console.log(req.ip)
    console.log(req.connection.remotePort)
    next()
})

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening')
})

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(clientIP)
    console.log(clientPORT)
}, 1000)
```

I set up an interval so that we can see if the variables are actually being updated. Initially, whenever the interval function runs, it prints null. But after I make a request to localhost:3000 it records my ip, and port and then it prints that out.

Comment: It worked! I think maybe I just had to wait so I will change the code to setTimeout, thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! I just used setInterval so that I can see if it actually worked and updated the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Under your http variable you can declare the variable

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var currentIP; // you can use "let" if you are using es6
```

then you can do the following inside of your function where you want to set the variable to req.ip.

```
currentIP = req.ip;
```

Comment: See thats what I thought but I just get `undefined` for `currentIP`

Comment: You get that after setting it to req.ip in the same function? So on the line below you set currentIP = req.ip, you do console.log(currentIP, req.ip), those two values are different?

Comment: @ns_helloworld 's answer worked, I think I just had to wait

Comment: Good to know! Good luck!